# @Cascade useless when making an insert?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, orm, cascade

This is my object **Utente**:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "utente")
public class Utente implements Serializable{
    ... 

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name = "id")
    private int id;

    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "utente")
    @Valid
    @Cascade(CascadeType.ALL)
    private Autenticazione autenticazione;  
    ...
}
```

This is my object **Autenticazione**:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "autenticazione")
public class Autenticazione implements Serializable{
   ...  

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name = "id")
    private int id; 

    @OneToOne(targetEntity=Utente.class)    
    @JoinColumn(name="utente", referencedColumnName="id") 
    private Utente utente;            

    ...
}
```

My goal is to save on the Db an object **Utente** and, using `@Cascade(CascadeType.ALL)`, save the relative object **Autenticazione** .

But I get the error `Column 'utente' cannot be null`, because **Autenticazione.utente** is null, since i'm saving the object Utente in that moment.

What should I do?

Should I save first the object **Utente** and then the object **Autenticazione**?
In this case `@Cascade(CascadeType.ALL)` is useless.

Thank you

Comment: JPA has "cascade" attribute of the relation annotations, which most certainly is not 'useless'. And why you would want to use some provider specific thing rather than that I've absolutely no idea

Comment: You've set the `Utente.autenticazione` object to the Autenticazione object, but you also need to set the `Autenticazione.utente` object to the Utente one. JPA does not do that automatically for you, because it cannot guarantee you really want to link to the same object.

Answer (score 0):

[Here](http://www.mkyong.com/hibernate/hibernate-cascade-example-save-update-delete-and-delete-orphan/) you can find some information about cascades, are you relating in both ways the objects?, for example:

```
Stock stock = new Stock();
StockDailyRecord stockDailyRecords = new StockDailyRecord();
//set the stock and stockDailyRecords  data

stockDailyRecords.setStock(stock);        
stock.getStockDailyRecords().add(stockDailyRecords);

session.save(stock);
```